# How to check value from looping every rows with spesific coloumn on datatable?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset

I want to loop every rows my datatable, the value from specific coloumn is 1,2,3. But, The value has checked only number 1. How to check every value from looping?

```
   Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("Select * from Compartment where OrderFK='1254'", con)
    dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

  Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Load(dr) 'Here from datareader
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim x As Integer = dt.Rows(0)("CNumber").ToString
        If x = 2 Then
            Loading_No.Value = 2
        Else
           loading_no.value = "Empty"
        End If
    Next
```

Thank you,

Comment: No idea what kind of control _loading_no_ is but this loop continuosly replace whatever you put in the Value property with the current loop value of x. Of course the only value you see is the last one put there.

Comment: Thank you. From my code is dt.rows(0) may the value is always 1. How to select dt.rows() for all count rows?

Comment: And how I can know? Whare is your query? What are your values in the datatable?. Again you loop until the end of the datarow set. but at the end only the last value is displayed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I has been edit my post. The value datatables with spesific coloumn "Cnumber" only 1,2,3. But when has tested, it's only loop for first row of the dataset. The first row is 1.
Just simple question. From my code, is true the code is loop every rows in datatable? My opinion, my code is "dt.rows(0)" that for first row, not for all rows.

Comment: What control is _loading_no_ ?

Comment: this is just html inputbox that has runat server. Just a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you loop with a foreach with the sets of rows retrieved by your query you should use the foreach indexer (row) to read the current value of the CNumber column, but instead of adding immediately to the TextBox add the retrieved value to a StringBuilder appending the current value to the previous read ones. At the end of the loop write everything in the TextBox value property

```
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("Select * from Compartment where OrderFK='1254'", con)
dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Load(dr) 'Here from datareader

Dim sb = new StringBuilder()
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim value = row("CNumber").ToString()
    if value = "1" OrElse value = "2" OrElse value = "3" Then
        sb.Append(row("CNumber").ToString & "," )
    End If
Next
If sb.Length = 0 Then 
    sb.Append("Empty")
Else
    ' remove the last comma '
    sb.Length = sb.Length - 1
End If
loading_no.Value = sb.ToString()
```

Notice also that you can remove the if test inside the loop modifying your query to retrieve only the records that you are interested

```
Dim cmdText = "Select * from Compartment where OrderFK='1254' " & _
              "AND CNumber IN(1,2,3)"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help steve, your answer is not solved my problem exactly, but your logic programming is solved my problem. Thank you very much steve for your help

Answer (score 0):

To find out how many rows your loop went through just put a counter into the loop. What I am wodering about is this line:
 Dim x As Integer = dt.Rows(0)("CNumber").ToString
You declare x to be an integer and assign a string to it?

Comment: Option Strict Off at its best

Comment: And then it's implicitly cast back to a number in his condition statement.

Comment: Yeah I'm declare to be an integer because the value is number. Could you share to me just simple line code for find out how many rows loop went trought?

Comment: First of all I suggest to set Option strict On. If you declare a variable as integer you must assign an integer to it and not a string, which you do. The counter will be set up like: Outside the loop: dim count as integer=0.Inside the loop: count+=1. After the loop has completed you can print this to the debug window: debug.print(count.tostring)